# Active page always showing as strong/bold, Code Igniter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination, codeigniter-pagination

The activate page is always bolded and somehow out of place. Not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm just trying to display the page links as individual links, planning to add CSS on later but can't seem to find out how to get rid of the active page link. Also, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Controller:

```
private function paginate_create_table($search = null)
{
    // Set pagination configuration
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/Home/on_hold_lot";
    $config['suffix'] = '?cust_drop_down='.$search['customer'].'&area_drop_down='.$search['stage'].'&status_drop_down='.$search['lot_status'].'&search_lot='.$search['search_lot'];
    $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].$config['suffix'];
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->home_model->fetch_lots('rows', $search);
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $results = $this->home_model->fetch_lots('array', $search, $config['per_page'], $page);

    return $results;
}

public function load_lot_table()
{
    // Get form values
    if($this->input->get())
    {
        $search = array(
        'customer' => $this->input->get('cust_drop_down'),
        'stage' => $this->input->get('area_drop_down'),
        'lot_status' => $this->input->get('status_drop_down'),
        'search_lot' => $this->input->get('search_lot')
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $search = array(
        'customer' => 'all',
        'stage' => 'all',
        'lot_status' => 'all',
        'search_lot' => ''
        );
    }

    // Paginate retrieved lots
    $results = $this->paginate_create_table($search);

    if($results != FALSE)
    {
        // Assign retrieved lots to assoc array
        $data['disp_rows'] = $results;

        // Create page links for Next page, Page 1 etc
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['links'] = explode("&nbsp;", $str_links);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['error_message'] = "No rows";
    }

    return $this->load->view('home/lot_disposition', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container text-right">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php foreach ($links as $link)
            {
                echo "<li>$link</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this code in your code(above in controller)

```
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
```

and add Bootstrap code for it.

```
// style
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';//this is active tab
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

On the active tab can use Bold(`<b>`) or any other styles

an this code is working without any error. **Tested**

My output(Without Bold Style)

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, was trying to understand and finally got it. Thank you!

Comment: @hzq happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config for your pagination like this,

```
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

and in view, you can just echo $links

```
 <div class="container text-right">
       <?= $links ?>
 </div>
```

**Rest everything will remain same, only `config` and `echo` in view**